# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I am getting this error when I enter Long 123456

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at thuchanh01.Baitap05.sumDigits(Baitap05.java:17)
at thuchanh01.Baitap05.main(Baitap05.java:31)
```

My code:
(Please note that the code is still complete and I have entered some print statements for checking)

```
package thuchanh01;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Baitap05 {
private static Scanner input;
public static int sumDigits(long n)
{
    String arrayN = Long.toString(n); //conver long to string
    int len = arrayN.length(); //length of string
    Character[] array = new Character[len]; //create char array with length = length string
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=len; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new Character(arrayN.charAt(i)); //assign array[i] = arrayN[i]
        sum = sum + array[i]; //result sum
    }
    return sum;

}

public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        long dayso;
        long sum = 0;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nhap vao day so = ");
        dayso = input.nextLong();
        sum = sumDigits(dayso);
        System.out.println("Tong can tim = " + sum);


    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid indexes for an array range from `0` to `len - 1`, but your `for` loop attempts to use an index equal to the `len`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=len; i++)
```

Change it to

```
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
```

to stop after the loop with `i` equal to `len - 1`.

To sum the digits, you must account for the fact that the `char` `'2'`, for example, doesn't have a numerical value of `2`; the Unicode (and ASCII) code is `50`.  In fact, all digits starting with `'0'` through `'9'` range from `48` through `57`.

Subtract the char `'0'` from the character to get the actual numeric value, because `'2' - '0'` is `2`.

```
sum = sum + array[i] - '0';
```

Comment: But I am trying to calculate the total 234, which means that 2 + 3 + 4 = 9 But the result returned is 153. It is wrong in this place?

Comment: I've amended my answer; you were adding the Unicode (or ASCII) values of the digits, not the numerical value of the digits.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
```

Characters start at index `0` and end at index `arrayN.length() - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<=len; i++)
{
        array[i] = new Character(arrayN.charAt(i)); //assign array[i] = arrayN[i]
        sum = sum + array[i]; //result sum
}
```

Change to i < len